# .kv file doesn't load in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

```
    #:kivy 1.11.1 

    <myManager>:
        connPage:
        myGame:

    <connPage>:
        name: "main"

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2

                Label:
                    text: "Password: "

                TextInput:
                    id: password
                    multiline: False

            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "mygame"

    <myGame>:
        name: "mygame"

        Button:
            text: "Go back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    import kivy
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    import os
    import sys

    kivy.require("1.11.1")

    class connPage(Screen):
        pass

    class myGame(Screen):
        pass

    class myManager(ScreenManager):
        pass

    kv = Builder.load_file("stylesheet.kv")

    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return kv

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        MyApp().run()


    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

How do fix this bug because I don't seem to find my error in my code
It could be an indentation error or a typo but I don't get any feedback in the terminal either
This is an attempt at a mobile gaming app in python with the kivy module
And all I get in the kivy window is a blavk screen, so it could be that the file is just never loaded.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.kv` file does not include any [root rules](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context), only class rules. `<class>:` is a class rule, `class:` is a root rule.

That means kivy *does* load your kv file, but the kv file only says "if you encounter a `myManager` class, style it this way.". You can either add a root rule or return the root widget manually.

root rule:

```
myManager:
    connPage:
    myGame:

<connPage>:
    name: "main"
    ...
```

return root widget in code:

```
kv = Builder.load_file("stylesheet.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return myManager()
```

There is another problem:

```
myManager:
    connPage:
    myGame:
```

The classes are all lowercase, so kivy will parse `connPage:` as adding a property to `myManager` with name `connPage` and value `None` (same for `myGame:`). To circumvent this name all classes uppercase. This is easy to miss, as it is only really discussed in [a small note](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#instantiate-children). Generally python encourages to follow the [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide - while normally this is purely style and does not change the meaning and behavior of your code, for the kv files it is important to distinguish between properties (attributes) and children (widgets). So the root rule should look like:

```
myManager:
    ConnPage:
    MyGame:

<ConnPage>:
    ...
```

and the classes should be named accordingly.

```
class ConnPage(Screen):
    pass

class MyGame(Screen):
    pass
```

Comment: I was a bit brief in my answer, I added some example code how you would define a root widget. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: still shows a black background tho, and its hard if you don't get feedback in the terminal to see whats wrong

Comment: You don't get feedback from kivy, because for kivy everything is fine. Apparently lowercase words are parsed as properties, whereas uppercase words are parsed children, so you should make your class names uppercase. I could only find this in the documentation [in a small note](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#instantiate-children), so it's easy to miss. Generally python heavily encourages uppercase class names.

Comment: well doing that it gives me:        ...
       2:
       3:<MyManager>:
 >>    4:    <ConnPage>:
       5:    <MyGame>:
       6:
 ...
 Invalid property name

Comment: Is it setup like I wrote in my post? It seems you not only changed it to uppercase, but surrounded the children by `<>`, which is invalid. Class Rules (i.e. how to style classes) are surrounded by `<>`, when you want to tell "add this class as a child` you just use `Class:`.

Comment: Oh no that is removed but still get the same black screen and this error

Comment: Did you copy the `...` from my code example into the file? That was just meant to as "replace this with the rest of your code", you would still need all the rest you have written, the classes should just be uppercase. If that is not the case, could you edit your post and append your current file? (Normally this is discouraged on stackoverflow, as it "changes the question" but I don't really know how else we could debug this quickly)

Comment: I didn't copy that, I left every as shown in the question.

Comment: So you didn't change the classes names to Uppercase versions? Can you add the current version and the entire traceback to the question?

Comment: yeah hold a sec

Comment: I did change them uppercase too and her is the traceback: line 624, in parse_level
     'Invalid property name')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\resume projects programmeren\game\stylesheet.kv", line 4:
 ...
       2:
       3:<MyManager>:
 >>    4:    <ConnPage>:
       5:    <MyGame>:
       6:
 ...
 Invalid property name